# Highcharts column chart with two different scales

Tags: highcharts

Is there a way to have a column chart with two different scales. I have played with the example from highcharts but the result is still not perfect: https://jsfiddle.net/dfq4b6xz/

The problem is that the columns are not in the center of there each section

[image]

```
$(function () {
    $('#container').highcharts({
        chart: {
            type: 'column'
        },
        title: {
            text: 'Efficiency Optimization by Branch'
        },
        xAxis: {
            categories: [
                'cat1',
                'cat2',
                'cat3'
            ]
        },
        yAxis: [{
            min: 0,
            title: {
                text: 'Employees'
            }
        }, {
            title: {
                text: 'Profit (millions)'
            },
            opposite: true
        }],
        legend: {
            shadow: false
        },
        tooltip: {
            shared: true
        },
        plotOptions: {
            column: {
                grouping: false,
                shadow: false,
                borderWidth: 0
            }
        },
        series: [{
            name: 'Employees',
            color: 'rgba(165,170,217,1)',
            data: [150, 73],
            pointPadding: 0.3,
            pointPlacement: -0.2
        }, {
            name: 'Employees Optimized',
            color: 'rgba(126,86,134,.9)',
            data: [140, 90],
            pointPadding: 0.4,
            pointPlacement: -0.2
        }, {
            name: 'Profit',
            color: 'rgba(248,161,63,1)',
            data: [null,null, 198.5],
            tooltip: {
                valuePrefix: '$',
                valueSuffix: ' M'
            },
            pointPadding: 0.3,
            pointPlacement: 0.2,
            yAxis: 1
        }, {
            name: 'Profit Optimized',
            color: 'rgba(186,60,61,.9)',
            data: [null,null, 208.5],
            tooltip: {
                valuePrefix: '$',
                valueSuffix: ' M'
            },
            pointPadding: 0.4,
            pointPlacement: 0.2,
            yAxis: 1
        }]
    });
});
```

Comment: So, is your question about dual y axes, or about point placement on the x axis...?

Comment: The placement on the x axis. There should be no gap for the missing column like the one in the screenshot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's caused by setting different `pointPlacement` for series. I suggest to use default setting for that option: http://jsfiddle.net/dfq4b6xz/1/

Answer (score 1):

You are specifically telling the chart to place the points in that manner, using the pointPlacement property:

```
pointPlacement: 0.2
```

and

```
pointPlacement: -0.2
```

Remove those lines altogether, and it works as it should:

- http://jsfiddle.net/jlbriggs/dfq4b6xz/2/

*[[EDIT - Pawel answered while I was typing my answer... same solution...]]*